# tensorflow model trained on keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array yields unexpected output shape of (sequence_length, 1)

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'm trying to train a tensorflow model where my inputs are a lagged timeseries of multiple features and I want to predict a single value.

Somehow the output shape ends up as an array of (lag/sequence_length, 1) when my lagged dataset has more than one feature, but I haven't been able to figure out why exactly that is. Here is a minimal example of what I'm trying to do

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import layers
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate some dummy data
x0 = np.array(range(300))
x1 = np.array(range(300)) * 2

df = pd.DataFrame({"x0": x0, "x1": x1})
y = np.array(range(100))

# also tried reshaping my y, but no help
# y = np.array(range(100)).reshape(100,1)

# make a dataset with lagged values
ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    data=df, 
    targets=y, 
    sequence_length=3, 
    sequence_stride=1, 
    sampling_rate=1, 
    batch_size=5
)

# show an example of what we are working with
list(ds.take(1))


# define simple model and train it
model = tf.keras.Sequential(
    [
        layers.Dense(32),
        layers.Dense(1),
    ]
)

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam())

model.fit(ds, epochs=4)

# make predictions on dataset
predictions = model.predict(ds)

# show predictions
predictions

print(predictions.shape)

"""
(100, 3, 1)
"""
```

If I create the dataset with only a single feature as:

```
ds = tf.keras.preprocessing.timeseries_dataset_from_array(
    data=x1, 
    targets=y, 
    sequence_length=3, 
    sequence_stride=1, 
    sampling_rate=1, 
    batch_size=5
)
```

My outputs are of expected shape.

Would appreciate any pointers. I'm guessing something is probably getting broadcast which then results in the output I'm seeing but I haven't been able to figure out what exactly is going on.